# stop duplicates when one part of the same record exists

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

i have a table called registry  and i have a couple of columns, for this example i am only going to state four(4) columns:-

- r_id
- file_number
- file_name
- volume

now these columns support duplicate filenumbers and filename but for each duplicate there needs to be a different volume. for eg.

```
r_id              filenumber            filename             volume
1                  123                   test                  1
2                  123                   test                  2
3                  234                   oracle                1
4                  234                   oracle                2
5                  123                   test                  1
```

now the issue is **r_id 5** which  has a duplicate volume as **r_id 1**.

so my question is how can i stop a duplicate volume when a record with the same file_number , file_name and volume exist?.

Nb.I am using the regular insert statement to create the records

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `unique` constraint on columns `filenumber, filename, volume`:

```
alter table table_name
add constraint fnumber_fname_vol_unique unique(filenumber, filename, volume);
```

Comment: thanks for your response however the table need duplicate inserts once the same volume does not exist for the same file. Check the example above. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent duplicate inserts see @Zakaria. If you want to ensure unique volume values, you could try along:

```
insert into data(r_id, filenumber, filename, volume)
  select
    data_sequence.nextval as r_id,
    123 as filenumber,
    'test' as filename,
    coalesce((select max(volume) + 1 from data where filenumber = 123 and filename = 'test'), 1) as volume
   from dual
;
```

See it in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/56810/3).

Please comment, if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.

Comment: thanks for your response but the above statement will only work if  i am importing data from and table which i am not. i am inserting via page items for eg filenumber =:p34_filenumber

Comment: @RawleMusgrave: Just noticed, some of the Fiddle has been lost. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/56810/3 - the table is checked for existing entries. If there is none for the filenumber/filename combination, volume count starts at 1... And, of course, you are not forced to use a sequence to get the r_id values...